# T-SQL and Stored Procedure gives different results with same query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, between

I am new to group. Have a weird issue. My T-SQL query returns 69 rows, but the same query in a stored procedure returns zero results.

In one of the posts in StackOverflow, someone has switched the parameters / variables in EXEC statement, but that too does not work for me as shown below.

Instead of `BETWEEN`, I also tried with `>=` and `<=`, but no luck.

Thank you.

```
SELECT 
    T1.CustKey
FROM 
    INVOICEROWS T0 
INNER JOIN 
    INVOICE T1 ON T1.INVKEY = T0.INVKEY 
INNER JOIN 
    ITEMS T2 ON T2.PARTCODE = T0.PARTCODE  
INNER JOIN 
    CUSTOMERS T5 ON T5.CustKey = T1.CustKey
WHERE 
    T1.INVDATE BETWEEN '2018-03-26' AND '2018-03-26'
    AND ((T1.CustKey BETWEEN 'ABC' AND 'ABC') OR (T5.CustGroupKey = ''))
    AND ((T0.ItemKey BETWEEN 'PQR' AND 'STU') OR (T2.ItemGroupKey = ''))
```

RESULT: 69 rows with same value 'ABC' (which is correct)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC1]
    (@DATEFROM AS DATE,
     @DATETO AS DATE,
     @CUSTKEYFROM AS NVARCHAR,
     @CUSTKEYTO AS NVARCHAR,
     @CUSTGROUPKEY AS SMALLINT,
     @ItemKeyFrom NVARCHAR(20),
     @ItemKeyTo NVARCHAR(20),
     @ItemGroupKey NVARCHAR(11)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT 
        T1.CustKey
    FROM 
        INVOICEROWS T0 
    INNER JOIN 
        INVOICE T1 ON T1.INVKEY = T0.INVKEY 
    INNER JOIN 
        ITEMS T2 ON T2.PARTCODE = T0.PARTCODE  
    INNER JOIN 
        CUSTOMERS T5 ON T5.CustKey = T1.CustKey
    WHERE 
        T1.INVDATE BETWEEN @DATEFROM AND @DATETO
        AND ((T1.CustKey BETWEEN @CUSTKEYFROM AND @CUSTKEYTO) OR (T5.CustGroupKey = @CUSTGROUPKEY))
        AND ((T0.ItemKey BETWEEN @ItemKeyFrom AND @ItemKeyTo) OR (T2.ItemGroupKey = @ItemGroupKey))
END
```

Running this stored procedure:

```
EXEC PROC1 '2018-03-26', '2018-03-26', 'ABC', 'ABC', '', 'PQR', 'STU', ''
```

returns zero rows

```
EXEC PROC1 '2018-03-26', '2018-03-26', 'ABC', 'PQR', '', 'ABC', 'STU', ''
```

also returns zero rows

Comment: have you tried removing the stored procedure element and simply put the code within the stored procedure in a query window and declaring the variables and running it? Does it return what you would expect? Can you remove portions of the where clause systematically and see at what point you start retrieving records? All of these are just basic debugging steps not much more that can be done without sample data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bet your problem is the **wrong declaration** of two of your stored procedure parameters:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC1]
    (@DATEFROM AS DATE,
     @DATETO AS DATE,
     @CUSTKEYFROM AS NVARCHAR,
     @CUSTKEYTO AS NVARCHAR,
     @CUSTGROUPKEY AS SMALLINT,
     @ItemKeyFrom NVARCHAR(20),
     @ItemKeyTo NVARCHAR(20),
     @ItemGroupKey NVARCHAR(11)
    )
```

You have `@CUSTKEYFROM` and `@CUSTKEYTO` declared as just `NVARCHAR`. This **means**: you get a string of **exactly ONE character** length! This is rarely what you expect or want.....

Try to declare those two parameters **with a length** - as you should **always** do! - and I bet now your stored procedure will return the desired results!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC1]
    (@DATEFROM AS DATE,
     @DATETO AS DATE,
     -- add explicit LENGTH to the NVARCHAR! However long you need it
     @CUSTKEYFROM AS NVARCHAR(25),
     @CUSTKEYTO AS NVARCHAR(25),
```

See [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) for a great and extensive explanation of this "bad habit" that you should really kick - right now

Comment: Thanks! That worked and I got 69 rows in Procedure as well!
Thanks for the link to the tips & tricks!

Answer (score 2):

In the stored procedure, you have declared the `@CUSTGROUPKEY` parameter as `SMALLINT`, but in the query you compare T5.CustGroupKey to `''`. When you pass the value `''` to a `SMALLINT` parameter, it becomes `0` and when you compare it to a nvarchar column <s>you are searching for a `'0'`</s>, you are forcing all the values in that column to be converted to a smallint, before the comparison (due to the precedence of data types). Although the wrong parameter type could cause errors, it's not the reason why you are not getting any results. See the answer of marc_s for that.

Comment: I see. So for a SMALLINT variable, what is the syntax for a '(blank)'?

Comment: You can use `0` or `NULL`, as appropriate.